# CSS3 loading animation inherit from previous div

Tags: html, css, animation

link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tUEg/1/

work in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/8tUEg/9/

I have been working the first set of loading animations.

Instead of having the spinners just switch color I would like them to:

1. inherit background-color from the previous div
2. work the darker background-color across as they rotate
3. repeat infinitely, moving the dark background-color to the first div, once it hits the end.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
.spinner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #007ACC;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-animation: rotateplane 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: rotateplane 2s  infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s  infinite ease-in-out; }
.spinner:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s .5s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s .5s infinite ease-in-out; }
.spinner:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s 1s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s 1s infinite ease-in-out; }
.spinner:nth-child(4) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s 1.5s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s 1.5s infinite ease-in-out; }

@-webkit-keyframes changecolor {
 0% {-webkit-transform: perspective(100px); }    
50% { background-color: #000; -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg)}
100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }     
}
```

Comment: You need `Javascript` for this, and you haven't tagged it, so nobody answered. But it's pretty simple to be honest. Let me know if a `JS` solution would work.

Comment: Very true, I was just trying to hone my CSS skills, which are very lacking, and I thought I recalled a css style that allowed inheritance of a previous sibling elements style but I must be wrong (like this but include it with the transition, http://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/)

Comment: There are `psuedo elements` that can perform `before` or `after` events, but it would **cascade** and produce further problems. Essentially, it would apply itself *(x)* times based on the number of listings. `CSS` is limited in logic, and is used to style. Luckily `javascript` has methods to style based on whatever logic you tell it.

Comment: @IntriquedMan Do you mean [**like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tUEg/4/)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was unaware of the nth-child css selector, put that up as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @IntriquedMan I did as you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to what Nicholas said in the comments, you can use a combination of animation delays and some child selectors to get what you want without any javascript

```
.example:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s  infinite ease-in-out; }
.example:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s .5s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s .5s infinite ease-in-out; }
.example:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s 1s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s 1s infinite ease-in-out; }
.example:nth-child(4) { -webkit-animation: changecolor 2s 1.5s infinite ease-in-out; animation: changecolor 2s 1.5s infinite ease-in-out; }
@-webkit-keyframes changecolor { 50% { background-color: #000; } }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tUEg/4/)

if you want the dots to be shaded differently on the start, you could use negative animation delays instead. For more CSS tricks similar to this, you may be interested in [my CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/) on the subject